# Rotating an Icon on click (Material UI)

Tags: typescript, material-ui

How do I rotate an icon (IconButton) on click, such that it is pointing down when the Collapse component is hidden and pointing up when the Collapse component is shown?

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<boolean>(false);

const handleExpand =() => {
    setExpanded(!expanded)
}

<Box>
<IconButton onClick={handleExpand}>
    <ExpandMoreIcon/>
</IconButton>
<Box>
<Collapse in={expanded}>Hello</Collapse>
```

I know I can use an Accordion, but I'm trying to avoid using one.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a check and render the `ExpandMoreIcon` and `ExpandLessIcon` based on the value of `expanded`.

```js
import ExpandLessIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess';

<Box>
  <IconButton onClick={handleExpand}>
    { expanded ? <ExpandLessIcon /> : <ExpandMoreIcon /> }
  </IconButton>
<Box>
```